# Firestore only returns 1 item

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

When I make a call to the firestore it returns the correct amount of items but shows them both as the sam item, rather than the 2 separate items

e.g I have a recipe for chicken curry and a recipe for salmon and rice but only the salmon and rice recipe gets shown

Here is my code to show the data I get back

```
import SwiftUI
import SDWebImageSwiftUI

struct CardView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var model: RecipesViewModel
    var body: some View {
        ForEach(model.Recipes,id: \.id) {item in
            VStack{
                ZStack(alignment: .bottomTrailing){
                    WebImage(url: URL(string: item.imageURL))
                        .resizable()
                        .scaledToFit()
                        .cornerRadius(8)
                        .frame(width: 150, height: 150)
                    HStack{
                        Text("\(item.likes)")
                        
                        Image(systemName: "heart")
                    }
                    .foregroundColor(Color(hex: "FF0044"))
                    .padding(5)
                    .background(.white)
                    .cornerRadius(8)
                    .padding(7)
                    
                }
                
                
                Text(item.name)
                    .foregroundColor(.black)
                    .fontWeight(.medium)
                    .font(.system(size: 20))
                    .padding(.top)
                
                
                HStack{
                    Image(systemName: "clock")
                        .foregroundColor(.gray)
                    Text("\(item.prepMins) mins")
                        .foregroundColor(.gray)
                }
                .padding(5)
                .padding(.trailing)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct CardView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        CardView()
        PopularRecipes()
        AllPopular()
    }
}

struct PopularRecipes:View{
    
    @State var presented1:Bool = false
    @StateObject var model = RecipesViewModel()
    
    var body: some View{
        
        VStack{
            HStack{
                Text("Popular")
                    .font(.system(size: 20))
                    .fontWeight(.medium)
                Spacer()
                Button {
                    presented1.toggle()
                } label: {
                    Text("View All")
                        .foregroundColor(.gray)
                }
                .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $presented1, content: AllPopular.init)
                
                
            }
            .padding(.horizontal)
            .padding(.bottom)
            ScrollView(.horizontal,showsIndicators: false){
                
                
                HStack{
                    ForEach(model.Recipes, id: \.id) {item in
                        CardButton()
                            .padding(.horizontal)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .environmentObject(model)
        .onAppear {
            model.getData()
        }
    }
}


struct AllPopular:View{
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    let columns = [
        GridItem(.flexible()),
        GridItem(.flexible()),
    ]
    @EnvironmentObject var model: RecipesViewModel
    
    var body: some View{
        VStack{
            HStack{
                Button {
                    presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                } label: {
                    Image(systemName: "arrow.left")
                        .foregroundColor(.black)
                        .font(.system(size: 30))
                }
                Spacer()
                Text("All Popular Recipes")
                    .font(.system(size: 20))
                    .fontWeight(.semibold)
                    .padding()
                Spacer()
            }
            .padding(.horizontal)
            ScrollView {
                LazyVGrid(columns: columns, spacing: 20) {
                    ForEach(model.Recipes, id: \.id) { item in
                        CardButton()
                    }
                }
                .padding(.horizontal)
            }
        }
        .navigationTitle("")
        .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
    }
}

struct CardButton:View{
    @EnvironmentObject var model: RecipesViewModel
    @State var presented: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View{
        ForEach(model.Recipes, id: \.id){item in
//            NavigationLink(destination: Recipe(name: item.name, cuisine: item.cuisine, difficulty: item.difficulty, dishType: item.dishType, prepMins: item.prepMins, prepHours: item.prepHours, cookMins: item.cookMins, cookHours: item.cookHours, restMins: item.restMins, restHours: item.restHours, likes: item.likes, imageURL: item.imageURL), label: {CardView()}).navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true).navigationTitle("").navigationBarHidden(true)
            Button {
                presented.toggle()
            } label: {
                CardView()
            }
            .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $presented) {
                Recipe(name: item.name, cuisine: item.cuisine, difficulty: item.difficulty, dishType: item.dishType, prepMins: item.prepMins, prepHours: item.prepHours, cookMins: item.cookMins, cookHours: item.cookHours, restMins: item.restMins, restHours: item.restHours, likes: item.likes, imageURL: item.imageURL)
            }



        }
    }
}
```

Here is where I get the data from the firestore

```
import Foundation
import Firebase

class RecipesViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var Recipes = [RecipesData]()
    
    func getData() {
        
        // Get a reference to the database
        let db = Firestore.firestore()
        
        // Read the documents at a specific path
        db.collection("Recipes").getDocuments { snapshot, error in
            
            // Check for errors
            if error == nil {
                // No errors
                
                if let snapshot = snapshot {
                    
                    // Update the list property in the main thread
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        
                        
                        self.Recipes = snapshot.documents.map { d in
                            
                            return RecipesData(id: d["id"] as? String ?? "", name: d["name"] as? String ?? "", cuisine: d["cuisine"] as? String ?? "", difficulty: d["difficulty"] as? String ?? "", dishType: d["dishType"] as? String ?? "", prepMins: d["prepMins"] as? Int ?? 0, prepHours: d["prephours"] as? Int ?? 0, cookMins: d["cookMins"] as? Int ?? 0, cookHours: d["cookHours"] as? Int ?? 0, restMins: d["restMins"] as? Int ?? 0, restHours: d["restHours"] as? Int ?? 0, likes: d["likes"] as? Int ?? 0, imageURL: d["imageURL"] as? String ?? "")
                        }
                    }
                    
                    
                }
            }
            else {
                
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and here is the struct of RecipesData

```
import SwiftUI
import FirebaseFirestoreSwift

struct RecipesData: Identifiable{
    var id: String
    var name: String
    var cuisine: String
    var difficulty: String
    var dishType: String
    var prepMins: Int
    var prepHours: Int
    var cookMins: Int
    var cookHours: Int
    var restMins: Int
    var restHours: Int
    var likes: Int
    var imageURL: String
}
```

[Here is an image of my output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8dcAl.png)

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix my error?

EDIT -
[console log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DaaLo.png)

Comment: Make sure the `id` variable is unique based on what I see it is likely empty for both

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are itterating in each childview over every item in your collection.

Remove this unnecessary `ForEach` loops:

***!Be aware!*** I had to mock your `FireBase` model implementation, so I don´t know if there is something wrong in your `getData()` or not.

```
struct CardView: View {
// Remove the environment viewmodel as you probably won´t need it
//    @EnvironmentObject var model: RecipesViewModel
// You need the instance of one recipy here not all of them, because this
// view should represent one instance of RecipesData
    var recipesData: RecipesData
    var body: some View {
//        ForEach(model.Recipes,id: \.id) {item in // Remove this loop
            VStack{
                ZStack(alignment: .bottomTrailing){
                    WebImage(url: URL(string: recipesData.imageURL))
                        .resizable()
                        .scaledToFit()
                        .cornerRadius(8)
                        .frame(width: 150, height: 150)
                    HStack{
                        Text("\(recipesData.likes)")
                        
                        Image(systemName: "heart")
                    }
                    .foregroundColor(Color(hex: "FF0044"))
                    .padding(5)
                    .background(.white)
                    .cornerRadius(8)
                    .padding(7)
                    
                }
                
                
                Text(recipesData.name)
                    .foregroundColor(.black)
                    .fontWeight(.medium)
                    .font(.system(size: 20))
                    .padding(.top)
                
                
                HStack{
                    Image(systemName: "clock")
                        .foregroundColor(.gray)
                    Text("\(recipesData.prepMins) mins")
                        .foregroundColor(.gray)
                }
                .padding(5)
                .padding(.trailing)
            }
//        }
    }
}

struct PopularRecipes:View{
    // As far as I understood is this your Top View so it is ok to create the viewmodel here
    @State var presented1:Bool = false
    @StateObject var model = RecipesViewModel()
    
    var body: some View{
        
        VStack{
            HStack{
                Text("Popular")
                    .font(.system(size: 20))
                    .fontWeight(.medium)
                Spacer()
                Button {
                    presented1.toggle()
                } label: {
                    Text("View All")
                        .foregroundColor(.gray)
                }
                .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $presented1, content: AllPopular.init)
                
                
            }
            .padding(.horizontal)
            .padding(.bottom)
            ScrollView(.horizontal,showsIndicators: false){
                
                // Yes. ForEach here in order to present all recipesData
                HStack{
                    ForEach(model.Recipes, id: \.id) {item in
                        CardButton(recipesData: item)
                            .padding(.horizontal)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .environmentObject(model)
        .onAppear {
            model.getData()
        }
    }
}


struct AllPopular:View{
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    let columns = [
        GridItem(.flexible()),
        GridItem(.flexible()),
    ]
    @EnvironmentObject var model: RecipesViewModel
    
    var body: some View{
        VStack{
            HStack{
                Button {
                    presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                } label: {
                    Image(systemName: "arrow.left")
                        .foregroundColor(.black)
                        .font(.system(size: 30))
                }
                Spacer()
                Text("All Popular Recipes")
                    .font(.system(size: 20))
                    .fontWeight(.semibold)
                    .padding()
                Spacer()
            }
            .padding(.horizontal)
            ScrollView {
                LazyVGrid(columns: columns, spacing: 20) {
                    ForEach(model.Recipes, id: \.id) { item in
                        CardButton(recipesData: item)
                    }
                }
                .padding(.horizontal)
            }
        }
        .navigationTitle("")
        .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
    }
}

struct CardButton:View{
// You don´t need the viewmodel here
//    @EnvironmentObject var model: RecipesViewModel
    @State var presented: Bool = false
// Again a single instance of RecipesData is all you need here
    var recipesData: RecipesData
    var body: some View{
// Remove the loop
//        ForEach(model.Recipes, id: \.id){item in
//            NavigationLink(destination: Recipe(name: item.name, cuisine: item.cuisine, difficulty: item.difficulty, dishType: item.dishType, prepMins: item.prepMins, prepHours: item.prepHours, cookMins: item.cookMins, cookHours: item.cookHours, restMins: item.restMins, restHours: item.restHours, likes: item.likes, imageURL: item.imageURL), label: {CardView()}).navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true).navigationTitle("").navigationBarHidden(true)
            Button {
                presented.toggle()
            } label: {
                //Pass the single RecipesData to your CardView
                CardView(recipesData: recipesData)
            }
            .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $presented) {
                Recipe(name: recipesData.name, cuisine: recipesData.cuisine, difficulty: recipesData.difficulty, dishType: recipesData.dishType, prepMins: recipesData.prepMins, prepHours: recipesData.prepHours, cookMins: recipesData.cookMins, cookHours: recipesData.cookHours, restMins: recipesData.restMins, restHours: recipesData.restHours, likes: recipesData.likes, imageURL: recipesData.imageURL)
            }



//        }
    }
}
```

---

I´ve tried to coment every decision I made. If you have question left don´t hesitate. But first please read and try to understand what changes I made and why. This is pretty much a simple default implementation. The errors you made are very basic.

---

### Edit:

Please change this in your viewmodel and add the console output to your question:

```
if let snapshot = snapshot {
        
        // Update the list property in the main thread
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            
            
            self.Recipes = snapshot.documents.map { d in
                
                return RecipesData(id: d["id"] as? String ?? "", name: d["name"] as? String ?? "", cuisine: d["cuisine"] as? String ?? "", difficulty: d["difficulty"] as? String ?? "", dishType: d["dishType"] as? String ?? "", prepMins: d["prepMins"] as? Int ?? 0, prepHours: d["prephours"] as? Int ?? 0, cookMins: d["cookMins"] as? Int ?? 0, cookHours: d["cookHours"] as? Int ?? 0, restMins: d["restMins"] as? Int ?? 0, restHours: d["restHours"] as? Int ?? 0, likes: d["likes"] as? Int ?? 0, imageURL: d["imageURL"] as? String ?? "")
            }

            print(Recipes) // add this
        }
        
        
    }
```

### Edit 2:

The error message in the console means that your ids are not uinque. But they have to be. You probaly didn´t set them as you created and uploaded them. You need to set an unique id for them either by

- loading the recipes adding an id and uploading them again
- editing the recipes online via Firestore console
- delting them and uploading new ones where the id is set to an unique value

To get an unique value you coud do:

```
id = UUID().uuidString
```

Comment: ok now I see 2 recipes because I have 2 recipes in the firestore but the 2 recipes shown are the same e.g the last recipe I added to the firestore shows twice

Comment: @elliotsilver Please see my updated answer. Also: do you get any error messages in the console? Something about `unique id`?

Comment: my output is [][]

Comment: I get this ForEach<Array<RecipesData>, String, ModifiedContent<CardButton, _PaddingLayout>>: the ID  occurs multiple times within the collection, this will give undefined results!

Comment: added console log to question

Comment: @elliotsilver As allready has been suspected your ids are empty. Please see my updated answer.